# Density of a projection random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and let $\mathcal {B}([0,1] \times [0,1])$ be our sigma algebra.

Define two random variables: $\xi(x, y) = x \ $  and $ \ \eta (x,y) =y$.

Find $\mathbb{E}(\xi | \eta)$ and $\mathbb{E}(\xi - \eta \ | \ \sigma (\xi + \eta))$.

My main problem is finding the densities of $\xi$ and $\eta$.

The variables are independent, is that correct?

Here is what I have so far:

$$\xi ^{-1}([a,b]) = \{ [a,b] \times [c,d]: \ \  c, d \in [0,1] \} $$ and it seems to me that the density of $\xi$ and $\eta$ is $1$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Could you tell me if I am right?

Comment: You are right, they are independent. The density is $1$, also correct. The preimage is wrong; you wrote something bizarre.

Comment: I see what you mean. This formula $\xi ^{-1} (x) = \{ (x, y) \in [0,1] \ : \ y \in [0,1] \} = \{x\} \times [0,1]$ is correct, isn't it? So $\xi ^{-1} ([a,b]) = [a,b] \times [0,1]$ ?

Comment: This is correct.